# Creating hour groups for time series data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a MySQL database with data recorded every 15 minutes. For simplicity, lets assume there are 2 fields:

```
DATETIME Created
Double Value
```

I would like to draw a chart which needs for each hour the opening, min, max, and closing values for an hour. To do this I need to return results from my MySQL query to my PHP to create a JSON. I would like to do this in the MySQL query so that the response is cached.

Here is an example of the problem, given 9 data points trying to get 2 hour groups:

```
Creation            Value
2014-03-25 12:15:00 413.17011
2014-03-25 12:00:00 414
2014-03-25 11:45:00 415
2014-03-25 11:30:00 415
2014-03-25 11:15:00 415.5
2014-03-25 11:00:00 415.5
2014-03-25 10:45:00 416
2014-03-25 10:30:00 416
2014-03-25 10:15:00 415.99
```

I would need:

```
Hour 1 (11:15:00 to 12:15:00)
Open: 415.5
Close: 413.17011
High: 415.5
Low: 413.17011

Hour 2 (10:15:00 to 11:15:00)
Open: 415.99
Close: 415.5
High: 416
Low: 415.5
```

Of course for the full 24 hours this would need repeating, this is just an example.
Any help is really appreciated!

Here is the current MySQL dump for the example (Using MySQL version 2.6.4-pl3):

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `exampleTable`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `exampleTable` (
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `exampleTable`
-- 

INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 12:15:00', 413.17011);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 12:00:00', 414);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 11:45:00', 415);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 11:30:00', 415);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 11:15:00', 415.5);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 11:00:00', 415.5);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 10:45:00', 416);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 10:30:00', 416);
INSERT INTO `exampleTable` VALUES ('2014-03-25 10:15:00', 415.99);
```

Comment: The lack of responses worries me, so I will shorten this question as much as I can.

Comment: Just as hint: If you can, you might want to split date and time into two columns (of types `date` and `time`). This way you do not need to cast `DATE()` on `created` everytime, but can use the new date column instead. You can then add an index to this column too, which speeds up your query. [See this sqlfiddle for an example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f117/2)

Comment: Even better: [combined index on both new columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f282/1). Avoids two filesorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Get it to work

You might try

```
SELECT
 DATE(created) AS day,
 HOUR(created) AS hour,
 (
   SELECT Value FROM `table` AS b
   WHERE DATE(a.created) = DATE(b.created)
     AND HOUR(a.created) = HOUR(b.created)
     ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1
 ) AS Open,
 (
   SELECT Value FROM `table` AS b
   WHERE DATE(a.created) = DATE(b.created)
     AND HOUR(a.created) = HOUR(b.created)
     ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
 ) AS Close,
 MIN(value) AS Low,
 MAX(value) AS High
FROM `table` AS a
GROUP BY DATE(created), HOUR(created)
```

this groups all your rows by DATE+HOUR and computes the MIN respectively MAX as `Low` or `High`. To find the first and last row for `Open` and `Close`, the easiest in SQL syntax is a subselect. It selects all rows which are relevant for the current row, and sorts them ascending or descending. Then selects the first row.

Please consider that this groups only by hour. Instead of

```
Hour 1 (11:15:00 to 12:15:00)
Hour 2 (10:15:00 to 11:15:00)
```

this groups like

```
Hour 1 (11:00:00 to 11:59:00)
Hour 2 (10:00:00 to 10:59:00)
```

If you want to keep the 15 minutes offset, you may subtract this from your created timestamp (`created - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE`) at all occurrences of `created` in the sql query above.

I created [a working sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67025/3) for you.

## Performance

Just as hint: If you can, you might want to split date and time into two columns (of types `date` and `time`). This way you do not need to cast `DATE()` on `created` everytime, but can use the new date column instead. You can then add a combined index to this new columns too, which speeds up your query. See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f282/1) for an example.

Comment: This looks like it will get me very close. My aim is to have it based on the most recent time in hour intervals. So, for example if the time is now 09:36, it should show 08:30 to 09:30 as one group. Then 07:30 to 08:30 as another. If I use this code, perhaps I can just calculate the offset first. I will have a play around with this and see if I can alter it, and I really appreciate your help (Upvote given, i'll accept it if/when I manage to get this to work)

Comment: Sure. If you encounter any problems, let us know.

Comment: Thanks GhostGambler. I changed my table I am testing with to use the same field names as your work (Value and created and table name to "table") but I seem to be getting a syntax error. It says:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table AS b
   WHERE DATE(a.created) = DATE(b.created)
     AND HOUR(a.created)' at line 5 

I will add the database table structure as a MySQL dump to the question, it may be something I have done wrong or explained wrong.

Comment: Please see that [`table` is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to put it into backticks if you seriously want to use it.

Comment: See my updated answer for a working sqlfiddle in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Ghost, that explains it. I've replicated that in my database and now I can work from here. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

To get your grouping right, you can use

```
 FLOOR(( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTable.dateCreated) - 900 ) / 3600)
```

where 3600 sets the interval at 1 hour and the - 900 sets the offset at 00:15

Since you need the MIN() and MAX for each of your four values, you'll need to JOIN the main table to itself but grouped by the min or max (based on the column).

finally, you have each sub-query (joined table) calculate the grouping hour above so you can use that to join them. Here's what I cam up with (with slightly different column names and

```
SELECT openDate,Open,Close,High,Low 
FROM   (SELECT FLOOR(( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTable.dateCreated) - 900 ) / 3600) 
               AS 
                      theHour, 
                      myTable.value AS Open,myTable.dateCreated openDate 
        FROM   myTable 
               JOIN (SELECT value,MIN(dateCreated) AS dateCreated 
                     FROM   myTable 
                     GROUP  BY FLOOR(( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateCreated) - 900 ) 
                                     / 3600) 
                    ) AS 
                                    aggTable 
                 ON aggTable.dateCreated = myTable.dateCreated) AS 
       openTable 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTable.dateCreated) - 900 
                               ) / 
                               3600) AS 
       theHour 
       , 
       myTable.value AS Close,myTable.dateCreated closeDate 
       FROM   myTable 
       JOIN (SELECT value,MAX(dateCreated) AS dateCreated 
       FROM   myTable 
       GROUP  BY FLOOR(( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateCreated) - 900 ) / 3600) 
       ) AS 
       aggTable 
       ON aggTable.dateCreated = myTable.dateCreated) AS closeTable 
              ON openTable.theHour = closeTable.theHour 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                                        FLOOR(( 
                 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTable.dateCreated) - 900 ) / 3600) AS 
                   theHour, 
                                                          MAX( 
                                                                  value) 
                 AS High 
                  FROM   myTable 
                  GROUP  BY theHour) AS highTable 
              ON closeTable.theHour = highTable.theHour 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                                        FLOOR(( 
                 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTable.dateCreated) - 900 ) / 3600) AS 
                   theHour, 
                                                          MIN( 
                                                                  value) 
                 AS Low 
                  FROM   myTable 
                  GROUP  BY theHour) AS lowTable 
              ON highTable.theHour = lowTable.theHour
```

Comment: Thanks for this - It looks good. It will take me a bit of time to understand exactly how it works, but i'll spend some time to understand it.

Comment: The important thing is to think of it as one outer query, and 4 inner queries, with each of the inner queries having a join, so it looks monstrous, but it's really the same pattern repeated over and over, with only slight changes to get the value you want for the top column. sorry it's a mess. I ran it through a beautifier that maybe isn't so beautifying for SO.